# hide div when empty - the good div call

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I am having trouble calling the right `div` to hide.

Underneath is my code and I would like to hide `li#spect1` if `#block1` is empty.
If I call, for example, the above `div #tab1` it will hide, but `#block1` will not.

Can anybody help me please?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$j(function() {
if ($j("div#block1").html() == "") {
$j("li#spect1").hide();}
});
</script>

<div class="content_container">
<ul class="tabs">
<li id="spect1"><a href="#tab1">Title of tab</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab_container">

<div id="tab1">
<div id="block1"></div><!--if div is empy = hide-->
</div>

</div><!--end tab_container-->
</div><!--end content_container-->
```

**EDIT**

`$J` is for calling jQuery or simple `$` on the Magento platform.

When `div#block1` is empty , hide `li` element `#spect1`.

It works when I put `#tab1` instead of `#block1` is empty, but I am searching a way to call `div#block1`. This won't work and I dont know why.

Comment: "above div #tab1"? "block will not"? I can't understand your question.

Comment: Why do you have $j() calling $j()? it looks like you're using jQuery so I'm not sure why you are calling it the way you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide the actual block as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$j(function() {
  if ($j("div#block1").html() == "") {
    $j("div#block1").hide();
    $j("li#spect1").hide();
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You could combine things here (IDs are unique and there is `.toggle(bool)` - `$j("#block1, #spect1").toggle($j("#block1").html() !== "")`.

Comment: @pimvdb, that wont work in this case since `#block1` is not a child of `#spect1`.

Comment: What do you mean? `$("aaa, bbb")` is not a child selector.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the tab1 div too :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$j(function() {
if ($j("div#block1").html() == "") {
$j("li#spect1").hide();
$j("#tab1").hide();
}
});
</script>
```